# What's the best way to invoke a large volume AWS lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am think of a service that might need to invoke a large volume of Lambda function at a short period of time. e.g. a chat bot in a very busy channel, the bot written in lambda get invoked on every new message. Lambda seems to be a great solution for this.

I wrote a simple test code with AWS SDK:

```
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({apiVersion: '2015-03-31'});

function invoke() {
  var start = new Date();
  var params = {
    FunctionName: 'test', /* required */
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    LogType: 'None',
    Payload: '{}',
  };
  lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    }
    else  {
      var duration = new Date() - start;
      console.info("Execution time: %dms", duration);
    }
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  invoke();
}
```

The lambda function "test" is a very simple one it basically do nothing just return the input event back. In lambda console it normally takes less than 10ms to execute. I tested in my own laptop so the network latency is about 200~300ms. A single invoke takes about 600~800ms from my dev computer.

Small batch run looks ok:

```
$ node test.js 5
Execution time: 637ms
Execution time: 652ms
Execution time: 646ms
Execution time: 713ms
Execution time: 850ms
```

However if I run it in large batch, the latency become dramatically large, and become larger and larger:

```
$ node test.js 1000
Execution time: 3569ms
Execution time: 4418ms
Execution time: 3571ms
Execution time: 4505ms
Execution time: 3661ms
Execution time: 3322ms
Execution time: 3645ms
Execution time: 3654ms
Execution time: 3651ms
Execution time: 4531ms
...
Execution time: 71851ms
Execution time: 70879ms
Execution time: 71777ms
```

I understand the AWS-SDK is actually making HTTP request to invoke the lambda, so it makes sense AWS will limit the concurrent connections and request might get queued and slow them down. So it seemed not that possible to invoke large volume of lambda in this way... :(

I am about to test it by sending the SNS, however not sure if that's a good solution since I would wish to get the result from those lambda functions.

Updated: I also put the code in another lambda function deployed to the same region, so I suppose the network latency is minimal, it looks definitely faster, but seemed to have same problem.

```
START RequestId: 7bd3339d-8986-11e5-85d1-67b32d2e2f9c Version: $LATEST
2015-11-12T21:44:00.923Z    7bd3339d-8986-11e5-85d1-67b32d2e2f9c    Lambda invoke #0
2015-11-12T21:44:01.003Z    7bd3339d-8986-11e5-85d1-67b32d2e2f9c    Lambda invoke #1
2015-11-12T21:44:01.005Z    7bd3339d-8986-11e5-85d1-67b32d2e2f9c    Lambda invoke #2
2015-11-12T21:44:01.063Z    7bd3339d-8986-11e5-85d1-67b32d2e2f9c    Lambda invoke #3
2015-11-12T21:44:01.065Z    7bd3339d-8986-11e5-85d1-67b32d2e2f9c    Lambda invoke #4
2015-11-12T21:44:01.122Z    7bd3339d-8986-11e5-85d1-67b32d2e2f9c    Lambda invoke #5
2015-11-12T21:44:01.123Z    7bd3339d-8986-11e5-85d1-67b32d2e2f9c    Lambda invoke #6
2015-11-12T21:44:01.124Z    7bd3339d-8986-11e5-85d1-67b32d2e2f9c    Lambda invoke #7
2015-11-12T21:44:01.124Z    7bd3339d-8986-11e5-85d1-67b32d2e2f9c    Lambda invoke #8
2015-11-12T21:44:01.182Z    7bd3339d-8986-11e5-85d1-67b32d2e2f9c    Lambda invoke #9
2015-11-12T21:44:01.182Z    7bd3339d-8986-11e5-85d1-67b32d2e2f9c    Execution time: 753ms
END RequestId: 7bd3339d-8986-11e5-85d1-67b32d2e2f9c
REPORT RequestId: 7bd3339d-8986-11e5-85d1-67b32d2e2f9c  Duration: 873.46 ms Billed Duration: 900 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 14 MB
```

My question is, is there a way to invoke large volume lambda at very short period of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke the Lambdas asynchronously (as @Matt Beckman indicates), and you need to increase your [Lambda account limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html). If you have to maintain state or retrieve returned results then you need to find another way to do that, e.g. append to an SQS queue or DynamoDB table.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch `InvocationType` from `RequestResponse` to `Event`, then your function will run your calls to invoke asynchronously.

Comment: I want to get the result back from the lambda function, I think InvocationType  Event won't get the result and I will have to find another way to get the result back?